# Unable to find popup window

Tags: selenium

I am having an issue with finding a popup window in some selenium test code.  I am looking at the screen on the test runner and there are two IE windows, one of them is the popup and one of them the page which generated the popup.  However selecting that window with

```
SelectWindow("name=SomeName")
```

fails.  Putting a break point in there and running some diagnostics shows that

```
GetAllWindowNames()
```

returns only one window.  Very odd.  I have duplicated the problem in IE, chrome and firefox so I don't think it is browser specific.  I am using C# to drive my tests.  Any idea how I might solve this issue?

**Edit:**

I looked a bit more at how this page actually creates its popup by reloading itself with window.open added to its code.  It is rather an odd way to open a popup but I don't see any reason why it isn't valid.

Comment: Have you tried selecting the popup window with selectPopup or waitForPopUp instead?

Comment: Yep, they just time out.

Answer (score 0):

Is there title or some other attribute in popup window's source code? You can locate that using any info you find there. Try to record open popup window in Se IDE and click on something in that popup window. Usually this trick works.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, there are some situations where SElenium fails to register the window. In this case you can register the window anyway by using the openWindow(´´, ). I think this is described in the explanation of openWindow in Selenijum IDE...